# Prove that $n^2(n^2+1)(n^2-1)$ is a multiple of $5$ for any integer $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove that $n^2(n^2+1)(n^2-1)$ is a multiple of $5$ for any integer $n$.

---

I was thinking of using induction, but wasn't really sure how to do it.

Comment: Maybe you should use induction.

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but wasn't really sure how to do it.

Comment: Start at n=0 and then proceed from n to n+1.

Comment: I think induction has no thing to do insuch questions, usually use conguruency

Comment: $(k^2-1)k^2(k^2+1)$ divided by $3.4.5$ gives A213547

Comment: @ThorbenKastenholz please add an answer using induction. I would be interested to see how you handle it.

Comment: @Joffan See my answer.

Comment: It's really not hard using induction. It's not the easiest way but you really don't need to think while doing it.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871353/prove-that-if-n-is-not-divisible-by-5-then-n4-equiv-1-pmod5

Comment: @quid No, it isn't. It can use that approach or others.

Comment: @Joffan I said *essentially* and as you could verify I did not vote to close as  *duplicate.* The two problems are equivalent by a very brief argument and so are *essentially* the same.

Comment: At least close "as duplicate" would not look as silly as close for being "off-topic." Jesus H. Christ!

Answer (score 11):

Hint:
$$
n^2(n^2+1)(n^2−1)\cong n^2(n^2-4)(n^2−1) = (n-2)(n-1)(n^2)(n+1)(n+2)
$$

Comment: This is by far the best answer. Definitely a very neat way to look at it.

Answer (score 7):

*Hint:* Compute $n^2\bmod 5$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4$.

Comment: How can you justify that checking for these five cases settles the question for any $n$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's because we only need to consider $n^2(n^2+1)(n^2-1)\pmod5$

Comment: @YvesDaoust If the only operations are addition and multiplication, then there are no problems. $$P(n)\pmod5 =P(n\pmod5)$$

Comment: @Farnight: that needs to be said.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't think it needs to be mentioned. It's one of the most basic rules of modular arithmetic.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Except that the function is not $\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor n-26n^3$. If we had that as out function, we'd have used some other method.

Answer (score 4):

${\rm mod}\ 5\!:\,\ \color{#c00}n^2(\color{#0a0}{n^4-1})\equiv 0\, $ by $\,\color{#c00}{n\equiv 0}\,$ or $\,\color{#0a0}{n^4\equiv 1}\,$ by little Fermat.

Or, directly $\,\color{#c00}{n\equiv 0}\ $ or $\ n\equiv \pm1,\pm2\,\Rightarrow\, n^2\equiv \pm1\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{n^4\equiv 1}$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $(n^2 - 1)(n^2 + 1) = n^4 - 1$. Fermat's little theorem tells us that $n^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$. This means that $n^4 - 1$ is a multiple of $5$ if $n$ is not, and therefore $n^2 (n^4 - 1)$ is also a multiple of $5$. For example, if $n = 2$, then $n^4 - 1 = 15$ and $n^2 (n^2 - 1)(n^2 + 1) = 60$.

This leaves us the case where $n$ *is* a multiple of $5$ to consider. Obviously $n^4 - 1$ is *not* a multiple of $5$. But $n^2$ is. For example, $n = 5$ gives us $15600$.

Answer (score 2):

$n^2(n^2+1)(n^2-1)=n^2(n^4-1)$ and $n^4\equiv1\mod5$ by FLT for $n\in\{1,2,3,4\}$

Or, as FLT also states that $a^{p-1+k}\equiv a^k \mod p$, and as the equation is $n^6-n^2$, the fact is immediate.

Answer (score 2):

If one wishes to use induction:

The statement holds for $n=0$, so let us assume it's true for $n=k$: $$k^2(k^2+1)(k^2-1)=(k-1)k^2(k+1)(k^2+1)=5m $$ and consider it for $n=k+1$. We have $$(k+1)^2((k+1)^2+1)((k+1)^2-1)=\\ (k+1)^2(k^2+2k+2)(k^2+2k)=\\ k(k+1)^2(k+2)(k^2+2k+2).$$ Suppose this isn't a multiple of $5$. Then none of its factor is, so our inductive hypothesis yields that for some integer $a,b$ either $k-1=5a$ or $k^2+1=5b$, or both:

- if both, then $$(k-1)+(k^2+1)=k(k+1)=5(a+b),$$ contradiction;
- if only the former, we have $$k+4=5(a+1),$$ whence $$ k^2+2k+2=25(a+1)^2-6k-14=25(a+1)^2-2(3k+7)=\\25(a+1)^2-2(3(k-1)+10)=5\left(5(a+1)^2-2\left(\frac{3(k-1)}{5}+2\right)\right),$$ contradiction;
- if only the latter, we also have for some integer $c$ $$k+3=5c,$$ whence $$k^2+2k+2=k^2+2k+7-5=(k^2+1)+2(k+3)-5=5(b+2c)-5=5(b+2c-1),$$ contradiction.

Comment: @rank Oops, of course, thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you've used the inductive hypothesis -- the substitution of $5m$ for $k^2(k^2+1)(k^2-1)$ is never used in the block of equations for the next case!

Comment: @Joffan, is it really a proof by induction if the proof doesn't make use of the inductive hypothesis?

Comment: @BarryCipra, Joffan Agreed, I did feel it was similar to what another answer had done, but didn't realize I wasn't doing induction. How about now? I dodn't make the substitution you refer to, but I do use that equation, right?

Comment: @Joffan How about now?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva impressive fix-up work! - not so straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

**Fermat's Little Theorem:** $p$ prime $\,\Rightarrow\, a^p\equiv a\pmod {p}$.

**Proof:** Clearly $0^p\equiv 0$. Assume $a^{p}\equiv a$. Then $$(a+1)^p\,\stackrel{\text{BT}}\equiv \,a^p+\binom{p}{1}a^{p-1}+\binom{p}{2}a^{p-2}+\cdots+\binom{p}{p-1}a+1\equiv a^p+1\stackrel{\text{ind. hyp.}}\equiv a+1$$

$\text{BT}$ refers to binomial theorem. I used $\binom{p}{i}\equiv 0,\,\forall i\in\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$.

It follows from $\binom{p}{i}=\frac{p!}{(p-i)!i!}$ and $p\mid p!,\ \ p\nmid (p-i)!i!$.

$5$ prime $\,\Rightarrow\, n^2(n^2+1)(n^2-1)\equiv n^2(n^4-1)\equiv n(n^5-n)\equiv n\cdot 0\equiv 0\pmod {5}$.

Answer (score 1):

In case $n$ is a multiple of $5$ the $n^2$ on the rhs is also.

If $n=2,3\pmod 5$ then $n^2\equiv4\pmod5$ , hence $n^2+1$ would be a multiple of $5$.

In the remaining cases, i.e.,$n=1,4\pmod 5$ then in $n^2-1= (n+1)(n-1)$ one of the term on the right will be a multiple of $5$.

So $n^2(n^2+1)(n^2-1)$ is always a multiple of $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof based on the fact that among any five consecutive numbers, one of them must be divisible by $5$.

Suppose that $n^2(n^2+1)(n^2-1)$ is not divisible by $5$.  Then either $n^2+2$ or $n^2-2$ *is* divisible by $5$.  Let's write this as $n^2+2\sigma=5k$, where $|\sigma|=1$.

But if $n^2(n^2+1)(n^2-1)$ is not divisible by $5$, then neither is $n(n^2-1)=n(n+1)(n-1)$, and therefore $5$ divides either $n-2$ or $n+2$.  Let's write this as $n+2\tau=5h$ with $|\tau|=1$.

Combining these cleverly, we can conclude $n^2-\sigma\tau n=5(k-\sigma\tau h)$, which implies $5$ divides $n(n-\sigma\tau)$, where $|\sigma\tau|=1$.  But that implies $5$ divides $n(n-1)(n+1)$, which is a contradiction.  Therefore $5$ must divide $n^2(n^2+1)(n^2-1)$.

Comment: I was liking where this was going in the first paragraph. If there was a way to do a half-upvote, I would.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is divisible by five, then $n^2(n^2+1)(n^2-1)$ is divisible by $5$, since $n^2$ is a factor.

Now suppose that $n$ is not divisble by $5$. Then $n=5m+r$ for some $r=1,2,3,4$. Note that $(n^2 + 1)(n^2-1) = n^4-1$.

$$n^4 = (5m+r)^4 = (5m)^4 + 4 (5m)^3r + 6 (5m)^2 r^2 + 4 (5m) r^3 + r^4$$ by the binomial theorem. We see then that $n^4 = 5\cdot M + r^4$ for some $M$. Now we just need to show that $r^4-1$ is divisible by $5$ to establish that $n^4-1$ is divisible by $5$.

This does follow by Fermat's little theorem. If that sounds foreign to you, it's easy enough to check by hand. $r$ can take four different values, $1,2,3,4$ (remember we already assumed that $r\neq 0$ since we are assuming $n$ is not divisble by $5$).

$$1^4 -1 = 0$$
$$2^4 -1= 15$$
$$3^4 - 1 = 80$$
$$4^4 - 1 = 255$$

Thus we see that, if $n$ is not divisible by $5$, then $$n^4 -1 = 5 M + r^4 - 1$$ and both $5M$ and $r^4 - 1$ are divisible by five. Therefore, $n^4-1$ is divisible by five, and $$n^2(n^2+1)(n^2-1) = n^2(n^4-1)$$ is divisible by $5$.