# How do I approach this contradiction proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

It's been driving me bonkers. As it's a contradiction proof I assume that there's a rational solution for the above equation. Then my prof told me to set the equation equals $0$, then sub in $p\over{q}$ for $x$, with $p$ in the set of integers and $q$ in the set of natural numbers, $ p ,q$ have no common factors, then factor everything by $q^4$, giving the equation [![enter image description here][2]][2][image]

Then I should use the fact that $2p^4 +6q^4$ isn't divisible by $5$, which means that those two terms will never subtract the other three terms in such a way that they all equal $0$, thus proving there's no rational solution.

I've checked it as a graph on Desmos and the proposition appears correct. However I'm at an utter lost for how to prove $2p^4 +6q^4$ isn't divisible by $5$ to proceed. I'm utterly lost and have scratched out so many failed attempts.

Answer (score 1):

HINT

If n is not divisible by $5$, then $n^4 \equiv 1 (mod 5)$

Comment: As surprising as this might sound, we haven't covered modular arithmetic(?) yet. But even after looking up what 1(mod5) means (1 right?) I don't get the hint.

Comment: Also, where did n come from?

Comment: $a\equiv b\pmod{k}$ is defined as meaning that $a-b$ is a multiple of $k$.  $n^4\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ means that $n^4$ is always one more than a multiple of five.  As $5$ is the same thing as zero modulo five, and so are any other multiples of five, the above equation simplifies to be $2\cdot\color{red}{1}+0+0-0-6\cdot\color{red}{1}\equiv 0\pmod{5}$ where the red ones are a direct result of the hint.

Comment: So now I have to ask where did n come from, why can you set $n^4\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, and how does this all prove that there doesn't exist some p and q such that $p^4$ + $q^4$ doesn't equal 5 or some multiples?

Comment: You can prove that $n^4\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ for every $n\not\equiv 0\pmod{5}$ by casework.  This proves that $p^4+q^4\not\equiv 0\pmod{5}$ for $p$ and $q$ not simultaneously multiples of five again by casework (*they can only add to be $1$ or $2$ mod 5*).  $n$ here was just selected as a placeholder so that the statement could be made generally and could be seen to apply to both $p^4$ and to $q^4$.

Comment: @LtotheV Sorry I was offline for a while ...  I feel JMoravitz gave perfectly good answers to your questions though ... are you still working on this? Here are [some proofs of the result that $n^4 \equiv 1$ for $n$ not divisible by $5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871353/prove-that-if-n-is-not-divisible-by-5-then-n4-equiv-1-pmod5) by the way. With modular arithmetic these are easiest, but with basic algebra you can see this as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Thanks for answering the OP's questions here!