# Are mathematical articles on Mathworld.Wolfram reliable?

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

[Based on this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744132/are-mathematical-articles-on-wikipedia-reliable) (wich existence tells me this is probably on topic also), another site that always pops out at the top in my mathematical definition searches is [Mathworld.Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/). How reliable is it?

Comment: It started out as Weisstein's encyclopedia of math, which was originally based mostly on excerpts from many other math sources and forums, e.g. sci.math, Schroeppel's math-fun mailing list, etc (e.g the Wronskian perspecitive in the [Mason's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MasonsTheorem.html) article is excerpted from one of my old math-fun posts, as are many others). So the quality varies widely since many articles have not been vetted by experts.

Comment: I remember seeing one that had a blatantly false statement in it, but I can't remember what it was or if it has been fixed.